# Finiteness requirement/non-requirement in Series results

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was given this result in the lecture notes of my course:

> Suppose that $I_1 \subseteq I_2 \subseteq I_3 \subseteq ...$ is an increasing sequence of **finite** subsets $I_k \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $\cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}I_k = \mathbb{N}$
>
> Suppose that $(a_n)$ is a sequence such that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \lvert a_k \rvert < \infty$
>
> Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k\in I_n} a_k = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k$$

I was then later on given a similar result, however in this case we had that $I$ is an infinite countable set and $(a_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ is a family of real numbers $a_\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ indexed by $I$.

> Then if there exists a bijective map $f:\mathbb{N} \to I$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \lvert a_{f(k)} \rvert < \infty$ and a family of **not necessarily finite** subsets $(I_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $I_1 \subseteq I_2 \subseteq I_3 \subseteq ...$ with $\cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}I_k = I$, then we have:
>
> $$\sum\limits_{\alpha \in I} a_\alpha = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{\alpha\in I_n} a_\alpha$$

My question is why is finiteness required for set of subsets in the first result but not for the second result?

Edit: Hey Brian, there were a couple of results proved/explained inbetween the two results mentioned.

> First, it was proved that if $L = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is an absolutely convergent series and $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is a bijection, then the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{f(n)}$ is absolutely convergent and has the same limit L.

> Then it was explained that if $I$ is an infinite countable index set and $(a_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ is a family of real numbers $a_\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ indexed by $I$, then if  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \lvert a_{f(k)} \rvert < \infty$, with $f: \mathbb{N} \to I$ a bijective map, and  $g: \mathbb{N} \to I$ is another bijective map, then we have that
> both
>
> $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \lvert a_{f(k)} \rvert = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \lvert a_{f(f^{-1}(g(k)))} \rvert = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \lvert a_{g(k)} \rvert$$
> and
>
> $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{f(k)} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}  a_{f(f^{-1}(g(k)))} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{g(k)}$$

> Then we are given the definition that we say $\sum\limits_{\alpha\in I_n} a_\alpha$ is absolutely convergent and write
>
> $$\sum\limits_{\alpha\in I_n} \lvert a_\alpha \rvert < \infty$$
> if
>
> $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \lvert a_{f(k)} \rvert < \infty$$
> for some (and hence any by the above result) bijective map $f: \mathbb{N} \to I$

Comment: Do the notes include proofs? Is it possible that between the first and the second result enough additional machinery was introduced to allow a stronger result to be proved?

Comment: Hey Brian, I edited the question with some additional results that were given between the two initial results.

Comment: At first, the sum over an unordered finite set makes sense because of commutativity, but the sum over an unordered inifinite set not yet. Then you get some results showing that under some condition (absolute convergence) the sum over an unordered infinite set is well-defined, thus from that point on, you can (for absolutely summable families) freely use sums over infinite sets.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your answer. I think I do understand what you've said here, but I feel like I'm still missing a step from going from what you've written here to actually proving the second result.